# Cannot add reference to a C# DLL from a C++/CLI project

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I've modified a simple c# library in VS2015 for RS232 control to work with my hardware device.  I can compile it into a DLL and then load that DLL from a c# test program and successfully send RS232 data.

Unfortunately I cannot get my c++/cli application, also in VS2015 with /clr and targeting platform version 8.1, to recognize the DLL.  If I try to add a reference I get:

"One or more errors occurred.

Could not add a reference to "C:\users...\file.dll" as it is not of a type or version current project can use."  (That typo is in the VS error message)

My application is 64 bit, but changing the dll to 32/64 bit does not seem to make a difference.  Not sure if it matters, but the ".NET target framework version field" in my project properties is grayed out and has not version listed, but I think that is normal for VS2015.